# Quality and Speed of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know how much first query  effect to speed of query or server 
Consider we have **50K** request during one minute .

First query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(13,1), ROUND(width, 1, 1)) FROM Home
```

.

And for second query we use `round` on client side, it means combination of client and server side

```
SELECT width FROM Home
```

Comment: Try them and find out what works best for you?

Comment: How can I test it for 50000 request, it's just depend on knowledge and experience   :|

Comment: it does not depend on knowledge and experience, it depends on benchmark of your hardware/software and nobody else.

Comment: Are you experiencing performance issues with it already and confirmed this is the bottleneck?  Or are you just trying to do premature micro-optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a tool such as SQL Query Stress to put a load on your server. This will allow you to simulate as many users as you want to execute the query as many times as you like;

http://www.sqlstress.com/

You could then use a tool such as Brent Ozar's fantastic sp_AskBrent to get some important metrics out of the system.

https://www.brentozar.com/askbrent/

Ultimately it's going to be down to you to see how your server performs in each instance and make a decision on which route to go down.